# Forge configurator inventor sample - run locally

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to run the sample application locally (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor) but get a lot of errors right after it spins up. I get no errors during the build process.

Any input is greatly appreciated - thanks

```
[11:04:15 INF] In Development environment
[11:04:16 INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
[11:04:16 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[11:04:16 INF] Hosting environment: Development
[11:04:16 INF] Content root path: D:\!projects\2020_10_forgeConfiguratorInventorSample\8\forge-configurator-inventor-master\WebApplication
npm[11:04:21 ERR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm[11:04:21 ERR] npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! forge-configurator-inventor@0.1.1 start: `rimraf ./build && react-scripts start`

[11:04:21 ERR] npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the forge-configurator-inventor@0.1.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


[11:04:21 ERR] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

[11:04:21 ERR] HTTP GET / responded 500 in 2830.2599 ms
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going to WebApplication/ClientApp and delete node_modules folder.
Then try again `dotnet run`.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, Michal. I tried deleting the node_modules folder under WebApplication/ClientApp and then run "dotnet run" from powershell in admin mode - unfortunately i get the exact same messages. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this issue, so I am just guessing here. Could you try to use the latest stable version of nodejs?
Also, there should be a possibility to build and run from VisualStudio if you have it.